# How to make Tkinter volume slider in a professional way

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a volume controller in python tkinter. But what exactly the problem is that, I want to make it look rich and professional. So when I tried using tkinter scale widget, it worked. But the widget is just a normal one. I wanted to know a way to make it look like the image below I have sent.

[image: Volume Slider]

My current one's code is this:

```py
def slider(self):
        self.scale = scale = ttk.Scale(self.canvas, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        print(self.scale.winfo_class())
        self.scale.place(x=580,y=455)
        self.scale.set(70)
```

**Is there anyway I can make it look better like the one in the Image?**

*What all things I want is:*

- A knob like round thing like in the image which is movable
- Some color should fill in the area that is already covered.
- A pop up or anything to show the current details of the volume.

I'm using pygame to play music in tkinter btw..
If this isn't possible, please suggest me a better way/alternative to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as easy as setting a theme for the TkInter project. Done in Python it looks like that:

`s.theme_use('themename')`

You might benefit from reading [Styles and Themes documentation of TkDocs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html#usetheme).

Comment: uh mate! I know it exists but I want a correct explanation/code on how to make it like the Image I send above. More specifically, I want the whole code for it. Moreover  `s.theme_use('themename')` doesn't satisfy my top 3 needs.

Comment: @The_Coder, What have you tried so far? Your sample code doesn't even show any attempt to modify the style at all? Your request is not just a simple answer.  I would suggest doing more research and attempting to style it first and then come back with specific questions on what you are having trouble with.

Comment: @Rory My question is specific. I have only put the necessary code in the question. If I want, I code spread my whole 4000 char codes. But that isn't the right part to be added. My question is, how to make the slider just look like the image. The current code which I showed you is mine which is just simple normal slider.

Comment: @The_Coder this is not to be taken personally as there are people here with far more experience that are helping to maintain the integrity of SO.  It was simply pointed out that your question isn't within the guidelines and understanding that will help you learn how to not only ask good questions but receive good feedback and answers.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no existing widget with a look exactly like what you are asking for. However, tkinter provides a way to craft your own widget styles, which might make it possible to do what you want.

Tkinter comes with a module named [ttk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html), which stands for "themed tk". It allows you to define custom styles for individual widgets, and to bundle those styles into a collection known as a theme. If you want to create a widget with a custom look, you can use this module to do so.

Unfortunately, being able to design a custom theme for a widget isn't very well documented. The best documentation I personally know of is on tkdocs.com, in the section [Styles and Themes](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html#usetheme). It gives a pretty good rundown of the terminology and overall description of how themes work. The python documentation for ttk also gives some additional information about creating styles and layouts in a section titled [Ttk Styling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-styling).

For inspiration, you can check out the code for the ttkthemes project ([github](https://github.com/TkinterEP/ttkthemes), [public documentation](https://ttkthemes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)) which has many different themes that you can examine. I doubt there is one exactly like you want, but you should be able to create your own after looking through the examples.